# Spring @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 29 2 THU") causing IllegalArgumentException Overflow in day exception

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduling

We have a **spring Boot(2.2.6-RELEASE)** **scheduler** running a job on **2024-02-29**, example one is shown below

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 29 2 THU") // A requirement to run a job far away from current time i.e on 2024-02-29
    public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
    }
```

It used to work fine, but it's started failing on **2021-07-29** which is a **Thursday** with the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Overflow in day for expression "0 0 0 29 2 THU"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.findNextDay(CronSequenceGenerator.java:223)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.doNext(CronSequenceGenerator.java:189)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.doNext(CronSequenceGenerator.java:184)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.doNext(CronSequenceGenerator.java:175)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.next(CronSequenceGenerator.java:148)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.nextExecutionTime(CronTrigger.java:88)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.schedule(ReschedulingRunnable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler.schedule(ConcurrentTaskScheduler.java:182)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.scheduleCronTask(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:431)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.scheduleTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:369)
```

**NOTE:** If I tested separately with spring boot version **2.5.3** it's working fine, but the same is failing with **2.2.6.RELEASE**, I can't do the same in the project

Answer (score 2):

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 29 2 THU")` is not **07-29**, it is 29th February.

You may want to try `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 29 7 ?")`

Documentation at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

**EDIT:** The following code worked for me

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 29 2 ?", zone = "CET")
    public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
        if(Year.now().getValue() == 2024) { //If you want specific year
            final long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like this documentation might make it clearer:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--

Answer (score 0):

So I did a bit of digging and I think the source for this version discrepancy is that 2.5.2 uses Spring version 5.3.8 while 2.2.6RELEASE uses 5.2.5RELEASE and in 5.3 the [CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) which was used to interpret [Crontab expressions](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) was deprecated because off (Quote) "and which has several known issues that none of the Spring team members felt comfortable solving."

The documentation for the (now) deprecated version is rather lackluster so I am not entirely certain what the error is and as it was a non breaking change they should parse the same values but as stated previously there were apparently serveral issues with it as CronSequenceGenerator was based on the deprecated [Java.util.date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html?is-external=true). Leapyears should theoretically be a non-issue but leapseconds are not supported. They should only happen in June and there wasn't one this year but that's how far my research has brought me. If you could maybe post what exactly you are trying to accomplish we might be able to tweak your Cronexpressions

Note: Even though Crontab specifies only 5 fields, the Spring implementation used 6